# Predicate concat in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate concat/3 with header concat(whole, part1, part2) that succeeds if part1 and part2 are two not-empty subsequences which when concatenated form the sequence whole. For example concat(A, [12, a, z],[1, 2, 3, 4])  answers with A = [12, a, z, 1, 2, 3, 4]. I've looked at append/3, but when I change it putting the whole as the first parameter it fails.

That is the modification I have done:

```
append(L, [], L).
append([H|R], [H|T],  L) :-
  append(R, T, L).
```

Comment: Can you show us how you changed `append/3` and it failed?

Comment: @rajashekar I have added the modification of my code that fails.

Comment: `append/3` is a predefined predicate. Are you sure it is actually loading without errors? Try renaming it to something and try it, it should work.